# SharePoint BDC - In the Entity Picker control when the user selects the entity a guid is added to the text

Tags: sharepoint, bdc

In the Entity picker when the user selects an entity the id appears in the text box next to the added bottom. Is this normal? Users are waiting a more meaningful name like the ProductName which is shown as one of the columns.